# difference between logger level and AppenderRef level attributes in log4j2

Tags: log4j

I am new to log4j2.x ,can anyone help me to understand the difference between **level** attribute in logger and AppenderRef in following code :

```
<Logger name="com.x.log4j2xml" level="debug" additivity="false">
<AppenderRef ref="File-Appender" level="error"/>
</Logger>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Here `"debug"` in the `Logger` element limits the log level we would handle within its sub-element `AppenderRef`, then it would have the error log in it with `"File-Appender"` handler. It would be no effect if the appender level priority is lower than logger, like here `"trace"` usage in appender.

Comment: I assume it is fine to leave out the level in the AppenderRef. I guess that this may be especially usefull if I want to be able to change the log level programmatically on the fly in the running application.